How to repair a down node in MongoDB Atlas?
I have a M10 replica set on MongoDB atlas under MongoDB 8 and one of the nodes is currently down since more than the 24 hours oplog window.
I have now this message “We are deploying your changes: 0 of 1 servers complete (current actions: resyncing 1 server, configuring MongoDB)”.
I tried to increase the cluster to M20, increase the oplog window to 72 hours and increase the node number to 5 without success.
How can I repair this node? Or how can I remove it and reload a new node?
Thanks for your help.

I exported the data, created a new cluster and imported the data into the new cluster.
Finally, I deleted the old cluster.
